# Firestore perform delete based on condition

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way I can perform a delete on `Firestore` documents where **field1 =x** and **field2 = y?**

I see the delete function but does not come with where.
If I use the transaction then there is get and delete but the get does not seem to accept "where" clause.

I hope I am missing something in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: You want to delete entire document or fields of particular document?

Comment: delete entire document whose fields match the condition

Comment: Its easy to delete document by doing query on single unique field against all the documents by `db.collection("yourCollection")
        .whereEqualTo("yourFieldName", "value")
        .get()` it will return list of documents. Suppose it return only one document then you can get its id by `document.getId()` and delete that document by `db.collection("yourCollection").document("gottenDocumentId")
        .delete()`

Comment: Yea but the issue if you have many documents then I need to do a loop on each one. I was hoping I can do it in one shot so it is one listener that tells me when everything is done since it async operation

Comment: I think this is not possible in one shot, but there is something called [WriteBatch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch) which can perform batch operations like update and delete at once. Please follow the documentation. Still I would suggest to delete the document in a loop and have a boolean variable true when all doc gets deleted in a loop.

Comment: The writebatch will still require doing query of the IDs seperately. The issue here is that if you generate all these deletions with all the listeners, how is it possible to know when the whole deletion is complete? I need to tell the user "deletion completed" but don't know how I can control when done

Comment: yes you need to create reference to document with the document ID like `DocumentReference doc1 = db.collection("yourDoc").document("docId1");` `DocumentReference doc2 = db.collection("yourDoc").document("docId2"); ...so on` for each document you got in query operation and then call `WriteBatch batch = db.batch();  batch.delete(doc1 );   batch.delete(doc2 ); .... so on `

Comment: I see. I guess what's left is how to know when all the deletion completed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to create the desired query first and then just use the `delete()` method like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference itemsRef = rootRef.collection("yourCollection");
Query query = itemsRef.whereEqualTo("field1", "x").whereEqualTo("field2", "y");
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                itemsRef.document(document.getId()).delete();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect. That's simple and elegant.I assume the delete is asynchronous. Is there anyway I can know when all the deletions are complete so I can display msg to the user

Comment: I haven't tried it, but my guess would be after delete() statement, add .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener...)  again, and nest the response.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my issue. but one question Don't you think we have to create batch and then execute it?

Comment: @Yash You may also add all those delete operations to a batch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my method for both querying and deleting documents from firestore. First it queries the data, then it deletes it.
Note, this method must be adapted for integer/double values.

```
    public void whereQueryDelete(final String collection, final String field, final String value) {
    mFirestoreDatabase.collection(collection)
            .whereEqualTo(field, value)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            String idDelete = document.getId();
                            mFirestoreDatabase.collection(collection).document(idDelete)
                                    .delete()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Delete method always returns onSucefful, independent if the document already exists or not.